# printing parent page and iframe contents from print button withing iframe

Tags: html, iframe, printing

I am using an iframe (I hate them by the way!) to call in a 3rd party checkout page into my parent page. The check out page doesn't allow me to pass any variables into it other than $total_amount. So, if an individual purchases 2 or more items they have no record of the items they purchase just the total amount. I have echoed the list of items purchased with php above the iframe for their reference. The final checkout step in the iframe allows you to print the receipt. However, it only prints the iframe content. **Can you tell a print button within an iframe to print the parent page as well?**

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell a print button within an iframe to print the parent page as well?

You would, if the iframe were in the same domain as the surrounding page.

Seeing as this is not the case here - the 3rd party checkout runs in a different domain -  the answer is sadly no. Cross-domain security prevents it.

Comment: Pekka,

Thanks for the reply. I do have the ability to host the iframe on my domain. If this is the case how would I create that print button?